# How to display FB button in GWT grid field

Tags: facebook, gwt, grid, field, share

I looking answer how display facebook share button in column of grid.

I have something like this:

[table image](http://www.jroller.com/sjivan/resource/grid-cell-widgets.png)

And I want replace inf button to fb button.

---

I use button code from this [site](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/trunk/DemoGwtShare/src/org/gonevertical/share/client/Share.java?r=2204).

---

In col. I must return Canvas object. Can somebody help me with it? My button in test working good, but when I want add it to main project it's not working and don't display.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the javascript sdk for facebook.
After the sdk has been initialized you can add HTML widget and set it's html to
<  fb:share-button href="site-you-want-to-share" type="button_count"  ><  /fb:share-button >

For more info on facebook sdk check this site
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/